# Proper way to activate LVM partition on multipath during the boot

Tags: debian, lvm, iscsi, multipath-storage

I have Debian 9 with successfully configured iSCSI and multipath:

```
# multipath -ll /dev/mapper/mpathb
mpathb (222c60001556480c6) dm-2 Promise,Vess R2600xi
size=10T features='1 retain_attached_hw_handler' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active
| `- 12:0:0:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 13:0:0:0 sdd 8:48 active ready running
```

`/dev/mapper/mpathb` is a part of LVM group `vg-one-100`:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/dm-2  vg-one-100 lvm2 a--  10,00t 3,77t
# vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg-one-100   1  17   0 wz--n- 10,00t 3,77t
```

`vg-one-100` group contains several volumes:

```
# lvs
  LV          VG         Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv-one-0-1  vg-one-100 -wi-a----- 20,00g                                                    
  lv-one-1-0  vg-one-100 -wi-a-----  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-10-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 20,00g                                                    
  lv-one-11-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 30,00g                                                    
  lv-one-12-0 vg-one-100 -wi-------  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-13-0 vg-one-100 -wi-------  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-14-0 vg-one-100 -wi-------  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-15-0 vg-one-100 -wi-------  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-16-0 vg-one-100 -wi-------  2,41g                                                    
  lv-one-17-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 30,00g                                                    
  lv-one-18-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 30,00g                                                    
  lv-one-23-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 20,00g                                                    
  lv-one-31-0 vg-one-100 -wi------- 20,00g                                                    
  lv-one-8-0  vg-one-100 -wi------- 30,00g                                                    
  lv-one-9-0  vg-one-100 -wi------- 20,00g                                                    
  lvm_images  vg-one-100 -wi-a-----  5,00t                                                    
  lvm_system  vg-one-100 -wi-a-----  1,00t
```

My `lvm.conf` includes the next filters:

```
# grep filter /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -vE '^.*#'
    filter = ["a|/dev/dm-*|", "r|.*|"]
    global_filter = ["a|/dev/dm-*|", "r|.*|"]
```

`lvmetad` is disabled:

```
# grep use_lvmetad /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -vE '^.*#'
    use_lvmetad = 0
```

If `lvmetad` is disabled, then `lvm2-activation-generator` will be used.

In my case `lvm2-activation-generator` generated all needed unit files and execute it during the boot:

```
# ls -1 /var/run/systemd/generator/lvm2-activation*
/var/run/systemd/generator/lvm2-activation-early.service
/var/run/systemd/generator/lvm2-activation-net.service
/var/run/systemd/generator/lvm2-activation.service

# systemctl status lvm2-activation-early.service
● lvm2-activation-early.service - Activation of LVM2 logical volumes
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/lvm/lvm.conf; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-03-28 17:20:48 MSK; 3 weeks 4 days ago
     Docs: man:lvm2-activation-generator(8)
 Main PID: 897 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting Activation of LVM2 logical volumes...
systemd[1]: Started Activation of LVM2 logical volumes.
root@virt1:~# systemctl status lvm2-activation-net.service
● lvm2-activation-net.service - Activation of LVM2 logical volumes
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/lvm/lvm.conf; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-03-28 17:21:24 MSK; 3 weeks 4 days ago
     Docs: man:lvm2-activation-generator(8)
 Main PID: 1537 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting Activation of LVM2 logical volumes...
lvm[1537]:   4 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg-one-100" now active
systemd[1]: Started Activation of LVM2 logical volumes.
root@virt1:~# systemctl status lvm2-activation.service
● lvm2-activation.service - Activation of LVM2 logical volumes
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/lvm/lvm.conf; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-03-28 17:20:48 MSK; 3 weeks 4 days ago
     Docs: man:lvm2-activation-generator(8)
 Main PID: 900 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting Activation of LVM2 logical volumes...
systemd[1]: Started Activation of LVM2 logical volumes.
```

The problem in: I can't automatically activate all LVM volumes during the boot because `lvm2-activator-net.service` activate volumes after it has been attached (logged-in) over iSCSI instead of multipath device (`journalctl` fragment):

```
. . .
kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] 21474836480 512-byte logical blocks: (11.0 TB/10.0 TiB)
kernel: sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 97 00 10 08
kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
kernel: sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
iscsiadm[1765]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2012-07.com.promise:alias.tgt0000.2000000155588d75, portal: 172.16.0.151,3260] (multiple)
iscsiadm[1765]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2012-07.com.promise:alias.tgt0000.2000000155588d75, portal: 172.16.1.151,3260] (multiple)
iscsiadm[1765]: Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2012-07.com.promise:alias.tgt0000.2000000155588d75, portal: 172.16.0.151,3260] successful.
iscsiadm[1765]: Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2012-07.com.promise:alias.tgt0000.2000000155588d75, portal: 172.16.1.151,3260] successful.
systemd[1]: Started Login to default iSCSI targets.
systemd[1]: Starting Activation of LVM2 logical volumes...
systemd[1]: Starting Activation of LVM2 logical volumes...
multipathd[884]: sdb: add path (uevent)
systemd[1]: Started Activation of LVM2 logical volumes.
systemd[1]: Started Activation of LVM2 logical volumes.
systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Mounting /var/lib/one/datastores/101...
systemd[1]: Mounting /var/lib/one/datastores/100...
multipathd[884]: mpathb: load table [0 21474836480 multipath 1 retain_attached_hw_handler 0 1 1 service-time 0 1 1 8:16 1]
multipathd[884]: mpathb: event checker started
multipathd[884]: sdb [8:16]: path added to devmap mpathb
multipathd[884]: sdc: add path (uevent)
multipathd[884]: mpathb: load table [0 21474836480 multipath 1 retain_attached_hw_handler 0 2 1 service-time 0 1 1 8:16 1 service-time 0 1 1 8:32 1]
. . .
```

Conditions to start `lvm2-activation-net.service` is correct:

```
# grep After /var/run/systemd/generator/lvm2-activation-net.service 
After=lvm2-activation.service iscsi.service fcoe.service
```

How can I properly activate `all` logical volumes during the boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to have a single physical volume, I really wonder how *partial* activation can happen in your case. It should be all or nothing. But here are a couple of issues to take care of anyway:

- You need persistent multipath device names. I'm not sure where `mpathb` comes from, but I recommend against enabling `user_friendly_names` in `/etc/multipath.conf` for clarity. Either configure the alias manually or use the WWID as provided by your storage.
- The LVM filters are regular expressions, not shell globs, so you need to change the syntax to something like

  ```
  filter = ["a|^/dev/mapper/222c60001556480c6$|", "r|.|"]
  ```

  (`global_filter` is optional for proper functionality, but it may make a difference for bootup times.)
- You have to delay activation until the multipath devices of all your physical volumes appear. One possibility is adding

  ```
  Requires = dev-mapper-222c60001556480c6.device
  After = dev-mapper-222c60001556480c6.device
  ```

  to `/etc/systemd/system/lvm2-activation-net.service.d/wait_for_storage.conf`. Another is creating a dedicated activation service.
- iSCSI storage devices (and their multipath devices) can take a long time to appear. You might need to create `/etc/systemd/system/dev-mapper-222c60001556480c6.device` containing

  ```
  [Unit]
  JobTimeoutSec=3min
  ```

  to make sure systemd does not time out too quickly waiting for it. Use symbolic links to a common file if you've got several such devices.

Even if the above does not immediately fix your problem, it will make debugging more tractable. Good luck!

Comment: I have already enabled `user_friendly_names` in `/etc/multipath.conf` (I forgot mention this). I will try your advises and let you know if it helps to me. Partly activated volumes are present because I activate it manually after boot. Thank's!

Comment: I've just added delay activation until the multipath device apper and it works. Thank you very much!!!